# XML template for Windows 10 Start & Taskbar customization deployed via Group Policy

Tags: xml, windows, gpo

First post on here, so please go easy :) !!

Im currently trying to quick fix a deployment another engineer has fudged and need some assistance with XML. Im fairly new to it but seem to be picking it up fairly quickly.

I created an output via PowerShell by running the Export-StartLayout to create a template file for my START MENU. I then deployed this via group policy and it worked a treat. I could see all my apps I wanted to shortcut to my start menu. But when I did some googling and tried to then add the customization of the TASKBAR, it doesn't work any more. If I try and open the XML directly, it says the following.

**End tag was not expected at this location. Error processing resource 'file://*-*-*/Repository/Windows 10/archive/Sta...**

That would say to me that there is something wrong with the  section of the code. I cant find anything that corresponds to it and iv tried taking the / out. But still it errors on the .

Heres my code. Can anyone help :) !?

```
<DefaultLayoutOverride>
<StartLayoutCollection>
  <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6" xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout">
    <start:Group Name="" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.Office.OUTLOOK.EXE.15" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="4" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="{7C5A40EF-A0FB-4BFC-874A-C0F2E0B9FA8E}\Microsoft Office\Office15\POWERPNT.EXE" />
      <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="2" Row="2" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default" />
    </start:Group>
     </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
</DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
**TOP PART IS ORGINAL XML FROM START CUSTOMIZATION. FROM HERE IS WHAT I ADDED**. 
<CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
  <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
    <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\programs\microsoft Office 2013\word 2013.lnk" />
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\programs\microsoft Office 2013\excel 2013.lnk" />
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\programs\microsoft Office 2013\powerPoint 2013.lnk" />
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\programs\microsoft Office 2013\outlook 2013.lnk" />
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Windows Explorer.lnk" />
    <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default" />
 </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
  </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
</CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated before I lose all my hair :) !!

Dan

Comment: You haven't posted code, you've posted an incomplete XML document. Without seeing the whole thing, it's impossible to tell what the problem is (the fragment you added is in itself well-formed, assuming namespaces `defaultlayout` and `taskbar` are defined).

Comment: Thanks for your response mklement0 (and sorry about my terrible English). I copied the contents of the XML file that id exported via powershell/created, as thats whats Windows uses to customize the appearance of the Start/Task bars.

Comment: If this is the whole XML document, then it's obviously broken, because end tag `</LayoutModificationTemplate>` is missing its `<LayoutModificationTemplate>` start tag. So for others to help you must update your question with 2 things: (a) show what the XML _should_ look like, precisely, and (b) add the relevant part of the PS code that produces the XML.